# google maps displaying a route

Tags: javascript, google-maps

according to google maps i can plan a route that crosses over several waypoints. It is explained here:http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Routes

Now the api wants me to add the waypoints like this:

```
location: waypoints
```

so waypoints is an array wich i have to assign to the location: parameter but from what ive seen in the demo they fill the array with strings of the locations.  What i was wondering if it was possible to pass the latitude and longitude instead of the strings?

update: this is the part where i try to create a route. i have put the same value in location throughout the entire loop for now but id doesn't work if i use variable values neither

```
function calcRoute() {

    var waypts = [];

    for (var i in owt.stores.spotStore.data.map) {
        waypts.push({
            location:  new google.maps.LatLng(12.3, -33.6),
            stopover:true
        });
        console.log(waypts);
    }
    var request = {
        origin: new google.maps.LatLng(50.82788, 3.26499),
        destination: new google.maps.LatLng(50.82788, 3.26499),
        waypoints: waypts,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}
;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [API reference](https://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsWaypoint):

> A DirectionsWaypoint represents a location between origin and destination through which the trip should be routed.
>
> **location**  LatLng|string   Waypoint
>   location. *Can be an address string or
>   LatLng. Optional*

So creating a new Waypoint with a lat-long value should be as below

```
return {
    location:new google.maps.LatLng(12.3, -33.6),
    stopover:true
};
```

Comment: ok i've done this but the status keeps saying ZERO_RESULTS, i have updated my post to show the function where i compile the routes, maybe you could have a look to see if something is wrong? This is only the last part of the code, since everything else is working correctly except for this part.

Comment: I put in the values `(12.3, -33.6)` just to show an example of how you might create a new point - like Jonathan has pointed out above, those coordinates are in the middle of the Atlantic Ocean! That's probably why you get no results. Also, in your code sample, your origin and destination are the same, that's by design, right?

Answer (score 2):

The way points can be either a string or a latlng.

http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Directions

In particular:

> waypoints[] (optional) specifies an
>   array of DirectionsWaypoints.
>   Waypoints alter a route by routing it
>   through the specified location(s). A
>   waypoint is specified as an object
>   literal with fields shown below:
>
> ```
> location specifies the location of the waypoint, either as a LatLng or as
> ```
>
> a String which will be geocoded.
>       stopover is a boolean which indicates that the waypoint is a stop
>   on the route, which has the effect of
>   splitting the route into two routes.
>
> (For more information on waypoints,
>   see Using Waypoints in Routes below.)

**EDIT**

Your way points are not valid for routing, i.e. they are in water - try centering a map on `(12, -33.6)`.

Here's a sample using way points (not the prettiest code, but it's an example ;) ).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var myRouter = {
            map_: null,
            directionsHelper_: null,

            stores: [
                    {name: "store1", location: new google.maps.LatLng(50.82788, 3.76499)},
                    {name: "store2", location: new google.maps.LatLng(51.02788, 3.9)}
                ],

            calcRoute: function() {

                var waypts = [];

                for (var i in this.stores) {
                    waypts.push({
                        location: this.stores[i].location,
                        stopover:true
                    });
                }
                var request = {
                    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(50.82788, 3.26499),
                    destination: "Antwerp",
                    waypoints: waypts,
                    optimizeWaypoints: true,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                };

                var _SELF = this;
                this.directionsHelper_.route(request, function(response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        _SELF.directionsDisplay_.setDirections(response);
                        return;
                    }
                    console.log('Directions Status: ' + status);
                });
            },

            init: function(mapid) {

                this.directionsHelper_ = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                this.directionsDisplay_ = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

                var center = new google.maps.LatLng(50.82788, 3.26499);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom:7,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    center: center
                }
                this.map_ = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapid), myOptions);
                this.directionsDisplay_.setMap(this.map_);

                this.calcRoute();
            }
        };

        $(document).ready(function() {
            myRouter.init('map');
        });

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #map {
            height: 500px;
            width: 600px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to google documentation the waypoint can be either a string or a LatLng object.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsWaypoint

here is an example using LatLng

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Directions Waypoints</title>
        <link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    var directionDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;

    function initialize() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(-40.321, 175.54);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 6,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: chicago
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        calcRoute();
    }

    function calcRoute() {

        var waypts = [];


stop = new google.maps.LatLng(-39.419, 175.57)
        waypts.push({
            location:stop,
            stopover:true});


        start  = new google.maps.LatLng(-40.321, 175.54);
        end = new google.maps.LatLng(-38.942, 175.76);
        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            waypoints: waypts,
            optimizeWaypoints: true,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                var route = response.routes[0];

            }
        });
    }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:70%;height:80%;">
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```